# How to remove virtual machine in vSphere

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere

I removed test virtual machine from inventory.

How to delete from Disk. I have using vSphere client.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the host, choose the 'Configuration' tab then under 'Hardware' choose 'Storage'. Right click on the datastore and choose 'Browse Datastore'. Locate where the virtual machine is located and then right click and 'Delete from disk'.